# Make a loop inside an other one in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working on PostGreSQL Version 1.18.1, and i am facing an issue :

I want to insert many informations and want to make it work like a loop, but for my request i need two loops (one inside the other)

my request look like this :

```
INSERT INTO table_hour (annee , mois , id_operateur , nombre_heure_sup , nombre_jour_recup )
SELECT 2017 , 2 , x.id , 0 , 0
FROM generate_series(1,6) AS  x(id);

INSERT INTO table_hour (annee , mois , id_operateur , nombre_heure_sup , nombre_jour_recup )
SELECT 2017 , 3 , x.id , 0 , 0
FROM generate_series(1,6) AS  x(id); 

...
```

**First Loop** : `id_operateur` From 1 to 6.

**Second Loop** : `mois` From 2 to 1000.

I want to knwo how to make it one inside the other (it's the value `mois` how will be the second loop)

Comment: I recommend you learn PL/pgSQL https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/plpgsql.html and you will be able to loop whatever you want

Comment: I dont see how your two insert could be nested - can you please elaborate post a little?.. and also please check your version with `select version()`

Comment: @nimdil  Thank you for the valuable link that you provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use cross join:

```
INSERT INTO table_hour(annee , mois , id_operateur , nombre_heure_sup , nombre_jour_recup )
SELECT 2017 , y.id , x.id , 0 , 0
FROM generate_series(1,6) AS  x(id)
CROSS JOIN generate_series(2,1000) AS  y(id);
```